# Backspace \b Chacacter Scope with regard to OS?

Tags: java, file-io, io, operating-system, backspace

I looked very extensively, but I was unable to find information regarding the scope of the `\b` character in Java.

Note: I am using Eclipse, and know that it provides limited to no support for the character. (side question if you want to answer:  looking for a console eclipse plugin supporting `\b` char)

I want to know two things:

> Can I write the backspace char to file to delete previously written test?
>   (I don't need to do this, but it reduces compatibility if I can't for my program)
>
> Can I delete a newline (`\r\n` or either) character with `\b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I write the backspace char to file to delete previously written test?

No.

> Can I delete a newline ("\r\n" or either) character with \b.

No.

The only situations where characters like `\b` will be interpreted like this are when you are writing to a screen, console or terminal.

Characters written to a file are not treated like this.

This is not a Java-specific restriction.  Rather it is inherent in the way that operating systems<sup>1</sup> handle writing data to files.

---

<sup>1 - That is ... every OS that I have encountered.</sup>

Comment: Setting aside \b, is there any way to write text in the middle of text written to the console/terminal?  For example, by moving the cursor in some way to the middle of the text, like you can do with inputstream (mark) in java.

Comment: It depends on the terminal / console.  For example, if the console / terminal supports "ANSI Escape Sequences" then you can.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Ultimately, the goal is to run the program in windows/linux terminals, which seem to support it.  How can I do so? CSI n F seems to be the correct code, but how can I use it in Java, if you have knowledge of this?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use external libraries.

Comment: @gagarwal - Start coding then :-)